# How to fix ssh login that starts asking for password and `ls .ssh` is permission denied?

Tags: terminal, macos, permission, ssh

I use my Mac to login to remote hosts via Terminal.app using `ssh` and local stored keys a.k.a. passwordless login a.k.a authentication key login.

All of a sudden the new `ssh` login attempts are:

1. asking for the password, where before the logins were passwordless
2. return `The authenticity of host XYZ can't be established.`
3. yes answering `Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?`
    results in `Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts)`.

Also `ls ~/.ssh` results in all "Permission denied":

```
ls: authorized_keys: Permission denied
ls: config: Permission denied
ls: id_rsa: Permission denied
ls: id_rsa.pub: Permission denied
ls: known_hosts: Permission denied
```

How to fix this?

Comment: TL;DR: version: **Question:** *The permissions are wrong.* **Answer:** *Fix the permissions.*

Comment: @Jakuje What does "TL;DR" mean?

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn't_read]((abbreviated tl;dr and tldr;))

Answer (score 1):

### Wrong file permissions

Wrong permissions are set on some files inside the .ssh folder. Have a look at it from Terminal.app:

```
$ sudo ls -l ~/.ssh
-rw-r--r--+ 1 user  staff    393 27 nov 19:08 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r--+ 1 user  staff     16 26 apr  2016 config
-rw-------@ 1 user  staff   1743 16 sep  2008 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff    400 16 sep  2008 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff  36654 26 nov 17:02 known_hosts
```

The first column (`-rw-r--r--`) displays the assigned [unix file permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions) for owner, group and others.

#### Read permissions for group and others are not allowed

The real issue here is not the first `r` on columns position 2, but the `r`'s on position 5 and 8. This tells that group and others has read permissions for these files. And that read permission for others else then the file owner, is not permitted.

#### Fix

It can be fixed by removing all rights from group and everybody using the command `chmod 600 filename`. For this specific case a command that would work is:

```
$ sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/{authorized_keys,config,id_rsa.pub,known_hosts}
```

#### Result

After running this command the new permissons look like this:

```
$ ls -l ~/.ssh
total 104
-rw-------+ 1 user  staff   393B 27 nov 19:08 authorized_keys
-rw-------+ 1 user  staff    16B 26 apr  2016 config
-rw-------+ 1 user  staff   1,7K 16 sep  2008 id_rsa
-rw-------+ 1 user  staff   400B 16 sep  2008 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------+ 1 user  staff    36K 26 nov 17:02 known_hosts
```

Note: the `ls` command now runs without `sudo`.

Comment: You should have read access on your public keys.